# About collapse panel which panel selected

Tags: select, panel, collapsiblepanelextender

I have a question about collapse panel..

I have a placeholder and I add more than one headerpanel, contentpanel, collapsiblepanel dynamically.. Here is my code :

```
    CollapsiblePanelExtender cpe = new CollapsiblePanelExtender();
    Panel pnlheader,pnlcontent;
    Label lblcontent,lblheader; Button btn;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        ///// PANEL HEADER VE ICERIGI //////////
        pnlheader = new Panel();
        pnlheader.ID = "PanelHeader" + i;
        pnlheader.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
        lblheader = new Label();
        lblheader.ID = "LabelHeader" + i.ToString();
        lblheader.Text = (i + 1) + ". Header";

        pnlheader.Controls.Add(lblheader);
        /////////PANEL CONTENT VE ICERIGI //////////
        pnlcontent = new Panel();
        pnlcontent.ID = "PanelContent" + i;
        pnlcontent.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkRed;
        lblcontent = new Label();
        lblcontent.ID = "LabelContent" + i.ToString();
        lblcontent.Text = "<table><tr><td border=\"1\">DENEMEE</td></tr></table>";
        btn = new Button();
        btn.ID = "Button" + i.ToString();
        btn.Text = "Deneme.Button";
        pnlcontent.Controls.Add(lblcontent);
        pnlcontent.Controls.Add(btn);

        ///////// COLLAPSEPANEL ICERIGI///////
        cpe = new CollapsiblePanelExtender();
        cpe.ID = "CollapsePanel" + i;
        cpe.TargetControlID = "PanelContent" + i;
        cpe.ExpandControlID = "PanelHeader" + i;
        cpe.CollapseControlID = "PanelHeader" + i;
        PlaceHolder2.Controls.Add(pnlheader);
        PlaceHolder2.Controls.Add(pnlcontent);
        PlaceHolder2.Controls.Add(cpe);
    }
```

How can I understand which panel expanded..

it is very important, please help..

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should to find all controls of CollapsiblePanelExtender type inside the scope of PlaceHolder2. 
Then you'll be able to get Collapsed property of each found CollapsiblePanelExtender instance.

Comment: how can I do this, can you explain.. I mean how can I understand that when panel clicked.. I can't handle click event and can't understand which panel..